# Как работает символьная таблица внутри PHP

Tags: php

Все мы знаем что есть `zval`'ы которые связаны с именами переменных. Но как именно связаны? Это и интересно!
Пару примеров чтобы объяснение отвечающего не было пустословным:

```
$a = 10;
$a = $a;
$a = $b
$a = &a;
```

Думаю этих примеров должно хватить, но если вы предложите еще то я не против, в любом случае жду интересные ответы по данному вопросу =)

Comment: Я думаю, Вам поможет эта статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/162713/

Comment: я думаю как Илья Бизунов, в сети полно объяснений. вот на что я сразу наткнулся, ставите вот это https://xdebug.org/docs/all и все видно воотчию, там же и исчерпывающие примеры.

Comment: @perfect это не символьная таблица! Я использовал xdebug, эта штука показывает не многое. Только часть значений zval контейнера. Почему вы все мне говорите про zval? Zval контейнеры и символьная таблица разные вещи аууу!
Если в сети полно объяснений, то поделитесь пожалуйста знаниями о символьной таблице или расскажите тут как она работает.

Comment: @MaximPro, вы спрашиваете: `Все мы знаем что есть zval'ы которые связаны с именами переменных. Но как именно связаны?` для этого достаточно xdebug. а если смотреть заголовок вопроса то тогда я не пойму о чем вы, для меня символьная таблица - это текущая кодировка.

Comment: @perfect символьная таблица != текущей кодировке, я так понимаю вы даже не слышали о таком понятии, ясно тогда почему меняя все отправляют читать про zval'ы. По поводу XDebuga и что же он мне может показать?

Comment: @MaximPro xdebug покажет вам информацию которую использует сборщик мусора. ну у меня теперь два вопроса к вам. 1) о не слышаном понятии, а вас не удивляет что на такой простой вопрос вам никто не дает ответа и не голосует за него? 2) что в вашем понимании символьная таблица?

Comment: @perfect Ну `информацию которую использует сборщик мусора`...ммм как интересно это по сути содержимое zval контейнера, xdebug отображает содержимое zval контейнера и точка! 1) За этот вопрос уже проголосовали люди, которым данный вопрос понравился, если бы вопрос был прост ответ бы уже был давно, многие тут хотят себе репутацию сделать, но я чего-то не вижу желающих и знающих об этом 2) Символьная таблица в моем восприятии это 2-мерный массив из пары ключ - значение, где ключ это имя переменной, а значение это указатель на контейнер zval

Comment: P.S Илья Бизунов тоже пытался мне что-то тут доказать, но все тщетно, все комментарии его были стерты кроме ссылки, которая ничего не дает! По его ссылке не показана символьная таблица и не показана работа символьной таблицы, там просто рассказывается что содержит переменная в php. Символьная таблица != Содержимое переменной. Символьная таблица != Текущая кодировка.

Comment: @MaximPro про то что вы думаете для меня не двумерный массив, а данные которые лежат в RAM памяти к которым обращается процессор который в свою очередь читает инструкции полученные из байт-кода который получился в результате чтения/обработки файла в котором записана программа (в данном случае на языке PHP).

Comment: @perfect Я не из воздуха взял "символьную таблицу". Я общался по этому поводу с зарубежными коллегами и они мне говорили про "символьную таблицу". И нет это никакой не байт-код. PHP не написан на байт коде он написан на С. Соответственно это должны быть какие-то организационные структуры написанные на С. Но проблема в том что я не смог отыскать это. А зарубежные коллеги мне описали так как я описал вам выше. P.S Ну если вы не знаете может не стоит тратить свое и чужое время, КПД в данном случае = 0. И меня данный факт очень сильно огорчает. Минусите...злой вы =)

Comment: если это php-массив то ее посмотреть можно. а то парадокс прям получается, таблица есть но никто ее не видел ) прям как с богом. найдете её буду рад взглянуть на это.

Comment: @perfect я не копался в исходниках, возможно там есть эта символьная таблица, но проблема в том что никто получается не интересовался как это работает. Всем просто тупо плевать. Ну работает как-то ну и пофиг. Мне же нужно для лучшего понимания языка в целом. Людей кто не интересовался этим сразу видно. Особенно видно тех кто кидает мне ссылку на zval контейнеры - гениально (нет). Как я говорил не стоит беседовать о том о чем не имеешь ни малейшего представления, это не грубость это реальность. Предлагаю закрыть тему разговора, а то это почти выливается в срач.

Comment: как скажете, без проблем )

Comment: @perfect для вас откопал рисунок с символьной таблицей, шах и мат атеист! https://habrastorage.org/files/633/fbc/1df/633fbc1dfb914465a76ea9cec923a672.png

Comment: @MaximPro , вам нарисовать рисунок как переменные в оперативной памяти лежат?

Comment: @perfect давайте, не откажусь! Посмотрим сможете ли вы меня удивить!

Comment: @MaximPro http://i82.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1116/19/89ca35d175cc9df1bb494dd4bd9fe719.jpg

Comment: @perfect технически да, именно так как вы нарисовали. Но тот рисунок не я рисовал. В большем случае чтобы понимать какой-либо язык достаточно сильно, необходимо знать то на чем он написан

Comment: @MaximPro а вот это правильно. на самом деле тот дух который все называют simbol table это имя переменной из исходного когда PHP интерпретатора. по крайней мере я себе это так представляю.

Comment: @perfect Если вы представляете себе переменную исходного кода как тип данных массив, я тогда соглашусь =)

Comment: @MaximPro если вам так приятно думать думайте так, а мне приятней так думать http://cpp.sh/3ow2y